# jQuery Hover mouseenter mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i´m trying to do a hover effect using this script:

```
function itemhover(){
    $(".item").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".mask").fadeIn();
    })
    $(".item").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".mask").fadeOut();
    })
}
```

The problem is that when I hover over any item it fades in the .mask of all, how can I point the function to just work on the item that is being hovered?

Also when I pass the mouse in and out on the item real quick, the fade effects goes crazy, is like it doesn´t stop, then it stop after a while, why is that?

thanks

Comment: What´s the relation between the element `.item` and `.mask`? You´ll have to traverse through the down to find that specific element based on the currently hovered element `$(this)`. Please include your HTML in the question for a complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your .mask element is contained within your .item element. If that is the case, then you can use `$(this)` to "set the scope" of the item being hovered (*this* refers to the item being hovered).

```
function itemhover(){
    $(".item").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find(".mask").stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    })
    $(".item").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find(".mask").stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    })
}
```

Also, you might want to chain `.stop(true, true)` before your *fade* animation effect to stop any previously queued animations and to jump to the end of the last queued animation.

Comment: this is perfect, it works well and no more animation strange effect. thanks!

Comment: yeah, the ".mask" is inside the ".item" thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

you can use the this statement

```
$(".mask",this).fadeIn();
```